# Google Analytics, filter ALL but a few URL parameters

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, regular-expression

My sites is being bombarded with new and old URL parameters. At first I tried to add those to the list of excluded URL parameters. With that list now exceeding 200, I wanted to try and use a GA advanced filtern.

However, the only filter I found would exclude ALL parameters:

> Create an advanced filter
>   Filter name: remove all query parameters from URI 
>   Filter type: advanced Filter field A: Request URI Filter
>   Field A pattern: (.*)\?(.*)
>   Field B: leave it blank
>   Output field: Request URI
>   Output pattern: $A1
>   Override output: YES Case Sensitive: NO

*[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/gJKinH03Z6M)*

The only parameters I'd like to not be filteted are *query* and *page*.
Does anyone know how to alter the regex accordingly?

Comment: They're standard Perl-like [regex](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en) patterns, so try: `^query$` in _Field A_ and `^page$` in _Field B_.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I was able to to solve my problem.

First I setup a new advanced filter:

```
Filter name:      remove all query parameters from URI except query and page   
Filter type:      advanced   
Filter field A:   Request URI Filter    
Field A pattern:  (.*?)\?   
Filter field B:   Request URI Filter   
Field B:          [\?|&](page=\d+|query=[^&]*) 
Output field:     Request URI Output pattern: $A1?$B1 
Field A required: YES   
Field B required: NO  
Override output:  YES   
Case Sensitive:   NO
```

In addition I created a second advanced filter which filters unnecessary ?
at the end of the URL, using the regex 
`(.*)\?$`